# Insert data from jtable to sqlite database

Tags: java, swing, sqlite

This is the code I used to insert data from jtable to database:

```
for(int i=1 ; i <= table.getRowCount() ; i++){

    String productid = table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
    String name = table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
    String quantity = table.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
    String totalprice = table.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();

    try {

        String query = "insert into sales (productid,customerid,name,quantity,discount,totalprice,paymentmethod) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, productid);
        pst.setString(2, customerid.getText());
        pst.setString(3, name);
        pst.setString(4, quantity);
        pst.setString(5, discount.getText()+"%");
        pst.setString(6, String.valueOf(totalprice));
        pst.setString(7, paymethod.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.execute();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
```

and when I click the button save it gives me an error.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1 at
>   java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source) at
>   javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source) at
>   gestioner.Sale$8.actionPerformed(Sale.java:332) at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: pls provide error stacktrace

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1
 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
 at gestioner.Sale$8.actionPerformed(Sale.java:332)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: If you have two rows, you count from 1 to 2?

Comment: i think your for loop should start from 0 not 1, change to this `for (int i=0...`

Comment: and stop before rowCount i.e: `i < table.getRowCount()...` so for loop will look like `for(int i=0 ; i <table.getRowCount() ; i++)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through Deafault table Model

```
public String getTableData (JTable table) {
DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
String tableData = " ";
for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
       // tableData = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);

String productid = table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
                    String name = table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
                    String quantity = table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();
                    String totalprice = table.getValueAt(i, j).toString();

                    try {

                        String query = "insert into sales (productid,customerid,name,quantity,discount,totalprice,paymentmethod) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
                        pst.setString(1, productid);
                        pst.setString(2, customerid.getText());
                        pst.setString(3, name);
                        pst.setString(4, quantity);
                        pst.setString(5, discount.getText()+"%");
                        pst.setString(6, String.valueOf(totalprice));
                        pst.setString(7, paymethod.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        pst.execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                  }
return tableData;
    }
```

Comment: its give me duplicated data on the database, it give me 5 rows, and on the jtable its only one row

Comment: @FadelD could you provide us screeshots of your jtable with data and select statment of sql queries.

Comment: i resolved the problem by deleting the loop with j and change the column count by 0 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 1):

based on error message, "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" you are trying to read an item out of the rows range; your for loop should start from 0 not 1, and stop before row-count, your for loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=0 ; i <table.getRowCount() ; i++){...
```